# Rasterizing image with colored fixed-width chars

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

uI am making a program to turn an image into coloured 0's, the problem is that the 0's are not colouring properly. To get anything near resembling the image I have to start my for loop at 2 and increase by 3 each time. The following is my current code:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        TextSelection textRange;
        TextPointer start;
        TextPointer startPos;
        TextPointer endPos;
        System.Drawing.Color x;
        int pixelX = 3;
        int pixelY = 8;

        InitializeComponent();
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"E:\Documents\Visual Studio   2015\Projects\RichTextBox Image to ASCII\RichTextBox Image to     ASCII\Akarin.jpg");

        for (int i = 2; i < 8000; i += 3)
        {
            textRange = richTextBox1.Selection;
            start = richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart;
            startPos = start.GetPositionAtOffset(i);
            endPos = start.GetPositionAtOffset(i + 1);
            textRange.Select(startPos, endPos);
            x = b.GetPixel(pixelX, pixelY);
            textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty,    new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(x.A, x.R, x.G, x.B)));

            pixelX += 6;
            if (pixelX > 1267)
            {
                pixelX = 3;
                pixelY += 16;
            }

            i += 3;
            textRange = richTextBox1.Selection;
            start = richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart;
            startPos = start.GetPositionAtOffset(i);
            endPos = start.GetPositionAtOffset(i + 1);
            textRange.Select(startPos, endPos);
            x = b.GetPixel(pixelX, pixelY);
            textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty,     new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(x.A, x.R, x.G, x.B)));

            pixelX += 7;
            if (pixelX > 1267)
            {
                pixelX = 3;
                pixelY += 16;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason that I am putting the code in the for loop twice is because when you take the amount of 0's that fit horizontally and find out how many pixels each 0 takes up, it comes to about 6.5 because of the space between each 0.

EDIT: Something else that is also strange, if you look in the top left corner where it starts colouring the 0's, 4 in a row are properly coloured, but then the rest are coloured every other.

Answer (score 1):

A few serious problems I'm seeing here. Normally when rasterizing you either loop through the source pixels or through the target pixels. You however... you loop by a fixed value of roughly 2666 ((8000 - 2) / 3). It's also a very bad idea to do things twice in a loop and even change the loop variable (i). Furthermore since you're having only one loop you have to care about both axes in one run. This is very error prone.

How about this approach?:

- Your source image is 1280 × 720 square pixels
- Since your zeros are not square you have to know their aspect ratio. If you know that you can calculate how many rows and columns you need. You probably don't want to match them 1:1 as this would give you a huge and stretched image.
- Once you know how many rows and columns you need, do two loops, one inside the other and call the loop variables targetX and targetY
- If your target image is supposed to be let's say 400 zeroes long in the x-axis, make the first loop go from 1 to 400
- Inside the loop pick one pixel (color) from the source at 1280/400 * targetX. Your first target pixel would be at x position `1280/400 * 1 = 3,2` which is roughly 3 (round the number after calculating it). The second would be `1280/400 * 2 = 6` and so on. I think this is the biggest pain in your algorithm since you're trying to get around the 6,5px width. Just round it after calculating! If the first is 6,5, make it 7, the second is 13... you get the idea.
- Same logic goes for Y axis, but you handle this with targetY.

Comment: Thank you! I have not tried what you suggested yet, but it seems promising!

Comment: I think the biggest problem you strumbled upon was the 6,5. You get into hell's kitchen if you multiply that. It's extrapolating floating point numbers which never goes right. So instead of thinking "One step is 6,5, so after X steps I should be at X * 6,5" better do "I've done N steps out of M which makes for n/m * distance"